# uninitialized constant Gem::Package on Heroku

Tags: heroku, gzip, tar

Attempt to use `Gem::Package::TarWriter` on Heroku

```
Gem::Package::TarWriter.new(tar_str) do |writer|
```

ends with error:

```
uninitialized constant Gem::Package
```

but everything is working locally.

[An article](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2010/08/rubygems-woes/) explains this so: “you are running gem install from a command window opened as administrator, when ruby itself was installed as a non administrator” (or vice versa).

Ok, but I don't have full control over Heroku.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I ran across it in a search when I ran across an `uninitialized constant Gem::Package`.

In my case, `require 'rubygems/package'` is what was needed. At some point that was not necessary, but now it is.